# .htaccess RewriteRule doesn`t work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use php`s module mod_rewrite to get rid of .php extensions in URL.
I`ve got 2 files in root directory **.htaccess** and **team.php**.

My .htaccess file contains following code. Consider each scenario separately.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  # Scenario 1 - http://localhost/team response with code 404
  # The requested URL /team was not found on this server.
  RewriteRule ^team$ team.php [NC]

  # Scenario 2 - http://localhost/teams successfully redirect to team.php 
  RewriteRule ^teams$ team.php [NC]

  # Scenario 3 - http://localhost/team response with code 404
  # The requested URL /team was not found on this server.
  RewriteRule ^team$ index.php [NC]

  # Scenario 4 - http://localhost/teams response with code 404
  # The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.
  RewriteRule ^teams$ index.php [NC]
</IfModule>
```

This means only Scenario 2 and Scenario 4 works properly and adds .php extension to URL. What is wrong with Scenario 1 and 3 ?

I also tried to use one more file **about.php** but it behaved the same way as team.php. For example request for localhost/about resulted in 404 /about not found on this server (Scenario 1).

How do i rewrite localhost/team request to load team.php file ? Is there possibly something wrong with the configuration, missing module or something with wrong permissions ?

Comment: Try changing `Options` line to this: `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution and it works now. Can you tell something more about it why it works ?

Comment: Just search: https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+multiviews+problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As anubhava said in his comment:

> Try changing Options line to this: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

This solved my problem and now RewriteRule works exactly as expected.